# Error when executing runpy.run_path from script

Tags: python, runpy

I have a small python file `c:\tmp\server_config` that defines a dictionary as follows:

```
conf = {'server1':'11.27.32.99',
        'server2':'11.27.44.42'}
```

I wish to access this dictionary from within another script. I can execute the following from the command line:

```
>>> from runpy import run_path
>>> settings = run_path("c:\\tmp\\server_config.py")
>>> settings['conf']
{'server1': '11.27.32.99', 'server2': '11.27.44.42'}
```

But however when I try to execute `settings = run_path("c:\\tmp\\server_config.py")` from within another script I get the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/Users/sjo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/startup.py", line 54, in 
settings = run_path('c:\\tmp\\server_config.py')
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 93, in _run_module_code
with _TempModule(mod_name) as temp_module, _ModifiedArgv0(fname):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 54, in __enter__
self._saved_value = sys.argv[0]
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'
```

What am I doing wrong (Python 3.7, Windows10)?

Comment: did you digure this one out I have problems as well, the modules inside the script I am calling are not recognized